# How to set current date with jquery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm making an edit profile form, and I'm using jquery iu datepicker to select DOB, now when user edits its data he/she has already some date in the profile field, now if the user wanted to change the date the datepicker pops up, how can I make the date from profile field to be selected on the date picker,

or simply how can I make datepicker display specific date when opened here is my current script:

```
$('#member_dob').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            defaultDate: ,
            yearRange: '1970:1992',
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','Maj','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dec'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Ned', 'Pon', 'Uto', 'Sri', '&#268;et', 'Pet', 'Sub']
        });
```

So for instance if my dob is 20.05.1987 , how could I set datepicker to display that date when opened, or just month and a year

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can assign a date object to default date setting to datepicker widget, for instance as default date 1980, February 2nd:

```
var d = new Date(1980, 2, 2);
$('#member_dob').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            defaultDate: d,
            yearRange: '1970:1992',
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','Maj','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dec'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Ned', 'Pon', 'Uto', 'Sri', '&#268;et', 'Pet', 'Sub']
        });
```

This should do what you need,

hope it helps, Sinan.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change an existing datepicker value you can do this :

```
$('#txtDate').datepicker().datepicker('setDate', 'today');
```

Comment: If the date picker already exist then `$('#txtDate').datepicker('setDate', 'today');` is enough

Answer (score 3):

You can put the default date into the `input` field:

```
<input name="date" id="member_dob" value="87-05-20" />
```

DatePicker will automatically selected that date when opened. Make sure the value match with `dateFormat` that you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if I get right what you try to accomplish here. First of all you need to pass the current DOB from the serverside to Javascript.

You can do that in two ways. One is to build a jsonObject, for example:

```
var jsonDate = {date : '1987-05-20'};
```

And then in your datepicker:

```
$('#member_dob').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            defaultDate: jsonDate.date,
            yearRange: '1970:1992',
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','Maj','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dec'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Ned', 'Pon', 'Uto', 'Sri', '&#268;et', 'Pet', 'Sub']
});
```

The second is to set a value for the Input you trigger you datePicker on :

```
$('#member_dob').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '1970:1992',
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','Maj','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dec'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Ned', 'Pon', 'Uto', 'Sri', '&#268;et', 'Pet', 'Sub']
   });

<input type="text" id="member_dob" value="1987-05-20">
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          firstDay: 1,
          showAnim: 'slideDown',
          dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        });
      $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
     });
```